# How can I rename an existing Spring MVC maven project

Tags: spring-mvc

I have an existing Spring MVC maven project. Everything in the current project is exactly what I need as a template for a new Spring project. Is there any way I can use the existing project as a template and rename it to a new project without changing anything but the name. I tried to recreate the existing project from scratch and just add the same existing components but am running into a lot of problems with the dependencies and other jar files as well as configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. All I did was select copy from the file menu and then it allowed me to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

First select your project, click on the File option in side of the file choose rename option then you can change the project name.